# php dom utf-8 encoding problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, domdocument, domxpath

I'm having issues with the encoding after executing queryXpath

```
<?php
header ( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
mb_internal_encoding ( 'utf-8' );
mb_http_output ( 'utf-8' );
mb_http_input ( 'utf-8' );
mb_regex_encoding ( 'utf-8' );

ini_set ( 'include_path', 'ZendFramework-2.4.9\library' );
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader ( array (
        'fallback_autoloader' => true 
) );
$autoloader->register ();

use Zend\Dom\Query;
use Zend\Debug\Debug;

$url = "http://expert.com.pt/115-5-programas/14865-02-809-002-00263-meireles-maq-lavar-loica-mll-125-w-5604409141651.html";

$ch = curl_init ( $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
$content = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );

$pdom = new Query ( mb_convert_encoding ( $content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8" ) );
// $pdom->setEncoding('UTF-8');
// echo $pdom->getEncoding();
$result = $pdom->queryXpath ( '//*[@itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"]' );
if ($result->count ()) {
    foreach ( $result as $r ) {
        // echo "----------------------------------------";
        if ($r->hasChildnodes ()) {
            $lbHtml = $r->C14N ();

            $dom2 = new Query ( $lbHtml );

            $nome_produto = $dom2->queryXpath ( '//*[@itemprop="name"]' );
            $ref_expert = $dom2->queryXpath ( '//*[@itemprop="sku"]' );
            $preco = $dom2->queryXpath ( '//*[@itemprop="price"]' );
            // *[@itemprop="image"] // small pic
            $imagem = $dom2->queryXpath ( '//*[@id="bigpic"]' );
            $peq_desc = $dom2->queryXpath ( '//*[@itemprop="description"]' );
            // *[contains(@class,"product-desc")]
            $url_prod = $dom2->queryXpath ( '//*[contains(@class,"pb-center-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4")]/p[4]/a' );
            $categoria = $pdom->queryXpath ( '//*[contains(@class,"breadcrumb clearfix")]/a[4]' ); // categoria

            if ($nome_produto->count ()) {
                foreach ( $nome_produto as $name ) {
                    $_arr ['name'] = $name->nodeValue;
                }
            }
            if ($ref_expert->count ()) {
                foreach ( $ref_expert as $ref ) {
                    $_arr ['ref'] = $ref->nodeValue;
                }
            }
            if ($preco->count ()) {
                foreach ( $preco as $_preco ) {
                    preg_match ( "/((?:[0-9]+,)*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/", $_preco->nodeValue, $_preco );
                    $_arr ['price'] = ( float ) str_replace ( ",", ".", $_preco [0] );
                }
            }
            if ($imagem->count ()) {
                foreach ( $imagem as $_image ) {
                    $_arr ['image'] = $_image->getAttribute ( 'src' );
                }
            }
            if ($peq_desc->count ()) {
                foreach ( $peq_desc as $_peqdesc ) {
                    $_arr ['description_small'] = $_peqdesc->C14N ();
                }
            }
            if ($url_prod->count ()) {
                foreach ( $url_prod as $_url_prod ) {
                    $_arr ['url_prod'] = $_url_prod->getAttribute ( 'href' );
                }
            }
            if ($categoria->count ()) {
                foreach ( $categoria as $_categoria ) {
                    $_arr ['categoria'] = $_categoria->nodeValue;
                }
            }

            // die();
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r ( $_arr );
```

the code always returns

> Array
>  (
>       [name] => **MEIRELES - MÃ¡q. Lavar LoiÃ§a MLL 125 W**
>       [ref] => 02.809.002.00263
>       [price] => 289.99
>       [image] => http://expert.com.pt/180503-large_default/02-809-002-00263-
>       [categoria] => 5 Programas
>  )

Comment: just to make it clear for me, what's your expected output?

Comment: [name] => MEIRELES - Máq. Lavar Loiça MLL 125 W 

the encoding in the correct way

Comment: the problem was the html output that i've filtered was not assuming the meta tag

Answer (score 0):

found the problem

for each Zend_DOM_Query($html) that i have i have to put the tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: on sub-queries as well